# client-side DEL request in express.js

Tags: javascript, rest, express

I'm trying to set up a simple REST API with express.js.  Having trouble implementing a delete function from client-side.

Routes:

```
module.exports = function(server) { 
  server.get('/entries/:id', entries.get)    // working
  server.del('/entries/:id', entries.destroy)// not working
}
```

i have a dummy delete button set up like this (using handlebars.js):

```
<form id='deleteform' action={{path}} method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DEL' />
  <input type='hidden'  name='_csrf' value={{csrf_token}} />
  <button class='submit' type='submit' name='DELETE'>
</form>
```

when i click the button, i get "Cannot POST /entries/1386113642" or whatever other url i set {{path}} to - however, GET requests for the same url work fine.  i also have methodOverride() set in my express config file.  what am i doing wrong here?

edit:  here is my entire app.configure() call:

```
    app.configure(function() {
        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.locals.pkg = pkg
            next()  
        })
    app.use(express.favicon())
    var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')
    var basePath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../..')
    app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/public'))
    app.use(express.static(basePath + '/backbone/'))
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/../../static')
    app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
       defaultLayout: 'main',
       extname: '.hbs',
       partialsDir: '../static',
       layoutsDir: '../static/layouts'
    }))
    app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
        app.use(express.cookieParser())
        app.use(express.bodyParser())
        app.use(express.methodOverride())
        app.use(express.session({
            secret: 'aekugwieufgkdjfhaisuefhwijfeijf',
            store:  new RedisStore({host:'localhost', port: 6379, client: redis })
        }))

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.locals.csrf_token = req.session._csrf
      next()
    })

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
                app.use(express.csrf())
            }
    app.use(app.router) 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEL` should be `DELETE`:

```
<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE' />
```

Comment: oh man, that was it.  now i have that programmer's remorse of having spent a lot of time stalling on something that had a trivial solution.  but thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> i also have methodOverride() set in my express config file

Post this code. It's not a config file. It is code that is highly sensitive to the order of middleware functions. In particular, make sure `bodyParser` comes before `methodOverride` which comes before `app.router`.

Comment: yeah, "config file" was the wrong terminology i guess.  it's the file where i do all the express configuration.  i just checked and i'm definitely calling the functions you mentioned in the correct order.